# Find features with at least 2 valid values in 2 groups (grouped filtering in R)

Tags: r, dplyr

In a table of features (genes) in the first col, I want to find all features that have at least 2 valid values (3 col: notNA) in at least 2 groups (second col).
Should be easily doable with dplyr but I cant wrap my head around it. A tidy-based solution would be appreciated.

Explanation on the data: The table summarizes how many valid values (eg > 10 counts in RNAseq) there are per group for each gene. It is used to filter out the genes that adhere to the criteria and allows exclusion of genes that show too few valid values/group (and would accordingly not be useful for further statistical testing).

```
library(tidyverse) # not needed but would be appreciated

df <- data.frame(
  gene = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B','B','B', 'C','C','C'),
  group = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b' ,'c', 'a', 'b' ,'c'),
  notNA = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4)
)

expected_result <- data.frame(
  gene = c('A', 'C'),
  total_valid_groups = c(2, 3),
  valid_groups = c('b;c', 'a;b;c')
)
```

Comment: I think it will help if you explain what a "valid value" is and how it is encoded by the `notNA` column. It's not obvious from the example data.

Comment: Thanks, I will clarify it. The notNA summarizes how many valid values (eg > 10 counts in RNAseq) are there in each group for each gene.

Comment: But the example data was useful from the beginning, kind of harsh to downvote it just because the origin of the notNA col wasn't clear to you...

Comment: thx, didnt mean to suspect you. Thanks for helping me to clarify the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>%
   group_by(gene) %>%
   filter(sum(notNA>1)>1, notNA > 1) %>%
   summarise(tot_valid = n(), valid_groups = str_c(group, collapse = ';'))

# A tibble: 2 × 3
  gene  tot_valid valid_groups
  <chr>     <int> <chr>       
1 A             2 b;c         
2 C             3 a;b;c
```